# How do I create sprite collision in PyGame using vectors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

https://github.com/maartenww/100daysOfCode_projectOne/tree/StackOverflow
(For reference here is the Repo to my code with a branch to code with the error, (so it's still readable for other people))

Hi, I'm creating a platformer and i'm stuck with a problem where I try to make collision between two sprites work using the pygame library.

```
class Game:

    def sprite_col(self, player_1, platform_list):
        sprites_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player_1, platform_list, False)
```

The sprites position is calculated with the use of pygame vectors

```
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # Player Constructor
    def __init__(self, player_width, player_height, player_color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.player_pos = vec(screen_width / 2, screen_height / 2)
        self.rect.x = self.player_pos.x
        self.rect.y = self.player_pos.y
```

I have no idea why the top code block doesn't run however.
I've googled my problem and looked at this video that I'm using for reference
:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN9pBx5ln40&list=PLsk-HSGFjnaG-BwZkuAOcVwWldfCLu1pq&index=3 (Skip to 8:40)

It gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 81, in 
    main()

File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 76, in main
    g.run(Player_1)

File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 65, in run
    self.update_game(player_1)

File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 58, in update_game
    self.sprite_col(player_1)

File "C:/ScrewAround/100DaysOfCodeProject1/main.py", line 41, in sprite_col
    sprites_hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player_1, platform_sprites, False)

File "C:\ScrewAround\100DaysOfCodeProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1524, in spritecollide
    spritecollide = sprite.rect.colliderect

AttributeError: 'pygame.math.Vector2' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

As you can see it's an AttributeError with Vectors and colliderect.
However I have no clue how this is relevant to my code and therefore
have no idea where the error is referring to.

Comment: sprite is a sprite, vector is a vector...

Comment: @FlashThunder Right but to what vector is the error referring? this really confuses me. and also why does the guy in the youtube video manage to do it?

Comment: Please don't post links to your files (repos), since they'll most likely be changed in the future and the links could get lost. Insert a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into the question instead. --

Also, we don't want to watch a 12 minute video in order to understand the question. Please describe how the code is supposed to work, what's going wrong and what you've tried to fix the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @skrx Ok I'll edit my question 
I do want to note however that the repo contains a branch with code that will not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Player` class, you have the following function:

```
def update_player(self):
    # Gravity
    self.player_vel.y += self.player_acc.y
    self.player_pos.y += self.player_vel.y + self.player_acc.y * .5
    # Acceleration
    self.rect = self.player_pos
    self.player_vel.x += self.player_acc.x
    self.player_pos.x += self.player_vel.x + self.player_acc.x * .5
    # Friction
    self.player_acc.x += (self.player_vel.x * -PLAYER_FRIC) / 1000
    if (self.player_vel.x > -.1) and (.1 > self.player_vel.x):
        self.player_acc.x = 0
        self.player_vel.x = 0
    elif(self.player_vel.x > 15) and (-15 > self.player_vel.x):
        self.player_vel.x = 15
        self.player_acc.x = 15
```

Note the line

```
self.rect = self.player_pos
```

`player_pos` is a `Vector2`. So, after this line, `self.rect` will be a `Vector2`, too.

But every function in the pygame library that deals with Sprites expects the Sprite to have a `rect` field of type `Rect`. Hence the error: `spritecollide` want to use `Rect.colliderect`.

You could use a custom collide function and use it in `spritecollide`, but IMHO it would be better if you would get rid of `player_pos` and just use the `rect` field to store the position of the Sprite.

Another way would be to just change the Rect to the position stored in the Vector, like you already to in the `__init__` function:

```
 self.rect.x = self.player_pos.x
 self.rect.y = self.player_pos.y
```

Comment: Thank you! ,this fixed my problem